# Detect corrupt JPG images in python (which module/library can do it)

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I read JPG's from an IP-camera and want to detect corrupt images.
This is my function to load the image:

```
from PIL import Image

def getImage(self):
  r=self.http.request('GET', self.snapshotURL, headers=self.headers)
  tmp=io.BytesIO(r.data)
  self.saveTmp(tmp.getvalue())
  image=Image.open(tmp)
  return(image)
```

If I receive a corrupt image, it's loaded to "image" without an error message by Pillow's `Image.open()`.
The result of `image.verify()` is `None` in this case.

To be able to inspect the received raw data, it's saved to a file with `saveTmp()`.

Here is such an image: http://dahlgrimm.de/Arduino/ip_cam/corrupt_image.jpg

If I look into the raw data of a corrupt file, the file starts with `FF D8 FF E0 10 4A 46 49 46` and ends with `FF D9`.
Thats normal and does not help.

ImageMagick's `identify` gives this:

```
corrupt_image.bin JPEG 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit sRGB 42KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

And the returncode is 0 == no help!

But if I open the file with gimp, gimp tells me: "Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment".

How can I (fast!) detect corrupt images with Pillow...or even any other library that's available for Python3?

**Edit:**

It's much better now with this function:

```
def isValid(self):
  if self.valid is None:
    t=datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S-%f")
    fn="/ramdisk/%s__corrupt.jpg"%(t,)
    f=open(fn, "wb")
    f.write(self.raw)
    f.close()
    if self.raw[-2:]!=bytes([255, 217]):
      self.valid=False
      #print("FF D9")
    else:
      rc=subprocess.call(["identify", "-verbose", fn], 
                          stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, 
                          stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
      self.valid=(rc==0)
      #if not self.valid:
      #  print("identify")
    if(self.valid): # temp. not remove corrupt images
      os.remove(fn)
  return(self.valid)
```

But I still get corrupt images. Neither `identify -verbose` nor `gimp` complain about these images.

Like this one:
http://dahlgrimm.de/Arduino/ip_cam/corrupt_image2.jpg

Maybe someone has an idea, how to also detect these remaining images !?

Comment: Add `-verbose` to force ImageMagick to read the entire image - as you currently have it, IM is only *"pinging"* the file header.

Comment: That works! Thanks. Now I have to see, how it can be used, if there is no file. Normally, the images are only in a python-variable.

Comment: `jpeginfo -c YourFile.jpeg` also finds no error.

Comment: Given that you specify that it has to be fast, I decided not to post Pillow's `Image.load()` as an answer, but it does trigger on both of your test images in my Py3-based corruption-detecting script with looser performance requirements, so thank you for the test fodder. (Speaking of which, if you took those, would you mind putting them out under a permissive or copyleft license so I can use them in test suites I intend to share around?)

Comment: @ssokolow: you can take the images as "Public Domain". Nevertheless....a link to my site (www.dahlgrimm.de) would be nice.

Comment: @dede Will do. Thanks. :)